# Input type="text" : displaying right part of content without rtl

Tags: css, html, forms, input

When an `<input type="text">` is filled with a long string and lose its focus, we only see the left of the string, but not the end. I would like to reverse this behavior, since in my use case the end of the string is far more important than the start.

With rtl properties, displaying is fine, but I still want to write left to right.

http://jsfiddle.net/9fqjz76h/

My use case includes readonly or disabled properties, so I can't "cheat" with focus and text selection.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Displaying is *not* fine. Try typing `a(1)` in the field, and you’ll see.

Comment: This? http://jsfiddle.net/1xt260ez/

Comment: Why do you use `input` for data that is not to be changed by the user? Making text overflow on left without messing up real text direction might be doable, but with `input` and without JavaScript, it looks like mission impossible.

Comment: I build a calculator with buttons to add characters into the input, so `input` seems to be the best "semantic" tag. But you are right, a `div` will be the way to fix my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Jukka : that's why I ask a solution, if typing was working, I would not have any problem. Benjamin : `text-align:right` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not against using jQuery, try this.

```
$('input').blur(
    function(){
        $(this).attr('dir','rtl')
    }
);
$('input').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).attr('dir','ltr')
    }
);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fqjz76h/3/)**